# Average of averages Excel formula

Tags: excel, array-formulas

how do I make a single formula that will take the n-week average of m-week averages?

Suppose I have data in `A2:A21`, and in `D21`, I want the 8 week average of 4-week moving averages up to A21.  So my idea would be

```
{=AVERAGE(AVERAGE(OFFSET(A21,-4+1-ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,8))+1,0,4)))}
```

So for example, with this data:

```
data    4 wk aver   8 wk avg avg
79      
79      
66      
38  66  
34  54  
13  38  
22  27  
50  30  
40  31  
98  53  
81  67  46
27  62  45
64  68  47
12  46  48
83  47  50
94  63  54
4   48  57
41  56  57
4   36  53
6   14  47
```

I am looking for a formula to calculate 47... My formula above calculates 57.8.

Comment: It would help if you showed some test data and expected outcome.

Comment: Yeah, so its slightly different, since I want the rolling averages, so some numbers are counted more times than others... I think I figured it out, will post solution below

Comment: So just to get this straight.  If you took the average of column1 and got 46.75, and then you too the average of column 2 and got 47.411..., and you took the average of column 3 and got an average of 50.4, you are looking for the average of 46.75, 47.411... and 50.4?  If so that average is 48.187...  The formula in your answer below is 47.0625.  Not saying your answer is wrong, just trying to understand what the original question was.

Comment: So column B has my 4-wk moving averages.  But then I want to find the 8-wk moving averages of column B, which are column C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is to use `SUBTOTAL()` on the inner average instead.  This will return a column of averages, so the outer `AVERAGE()` will have the correct behavior.

```
{=AVERAGE(SUBTOTAL(1,OFFSET(A21,-4+1-ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,8))+1,0,4)))}
```

The reason the original solution didn't work is because the inner `AVERAGE` was just taking the total average of all the arrays, instead of returning a column of their individual averages.  I find this `SUBTOTAL()` trick useful when you need to do this kind of thing.